# Etale-analytic comparison without elementary fibrations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

A theorem due to Artin states that for a smooth scheme $X$ of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ and a locally constant constructible sheaf $F$ we have an isomorphism 
$$
H^*_{et}(X, F)\approx H^*(X(\mathbb{C}), F)
$$
where the LHS is etale cohomology and the RHS is derived-functor cohomology of $F$ in analytic topology. One proof I know proceeds by establishing that there is an open covering of $X$ by $K(\pi, 1)$ spaces. However, the appearance of $K(\pi, 1)$'s feels somewhat weird to me. Is there an alternative proof that does not rely on $K(\pi, 1)$ neighbourhoods?

Comment: Yes, check one of the following exposes of SGA4.3.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger do you mean SGA 4, Expose 16, theorem 4.1?

Comment: Exactly. A mush stronger result (no smoothness assumptions on $X$ and $F$), proved by devissage with reduction to curves, but without elementary fibrations.